# Optimizar código reduciendo tiempo ejecución

Tags: python, optimización, profiler

Trato de optimizar este sencillo código para  reducir el tiempo de ejecución.

No consigo proponer nada que ayude a la solución. He conseguido otros códigos que reduzcan el tiempo, pero no consigo hacerlo sobre este.

```
def squaresum(n):
"""Returns the sum of squares of first n natural numbers.

Parameters:
    n (int): positive integer.

Returns:
    (int): sum of squares from 1 to n (inclusive).
"""
total = 0
operands = []
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    aux = pow(i, 2)
    operands.append(aux)

for op in operands:
    total = total + op

return total
```

He observado los tiempos de ejecución por línea con :

```
%load_ext line_profiler

%lprun -f squaresum squaresum(2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Otra forma de mejorar la función es aplicando el hecho de que:

```
La suma de los cuadrados de los primeros n números naturales es igual a:

n(n+1)(2n+1)/6
```

Esta forma de hacerlo es, por supuesto, puramente matemática.

Por lo que tendríamos que:

```
def squaresum(n):
    """Returns the sum of squares of first n natural numbers.

    Parameters:
    n (int): positive integer.

    Returns:
    (int): sum of squares from 1 to n (inclusive).
    """
    return n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) // 6;
```

Comment: Buena respuesta aunque no era exactamente lo que buscaba, pero gracias por tu propuesta.

Comment: Sin duda esta es la forma más óptima y eficiente, precisamente por ser puramente matemática. Alguien más debería votarla!

Answer (score 2):

El tiempo de tu primer ciclo for se puede reducir con una compresion de lista y para la suma se puede utilizar la funcion `sum(iterable)`

```py
 %load_ext line_profiler
def squaresum(n):
  """Returns the sum of squares of first n natural numbers.
  
  Parameters:
      n (int): positive integer.

  Returns:
      (int): sum of squares from 1 to n (inclusive).
  """
  operands = [pow(1,2) for i in range(1, n+1)]
  total = sum(operands)

  return total
%lprun -f squaresum squaresum(2)
```

Donde para `%lprun -f squaresum squaresum(10000000)` el tiempo total es `Total time: 4.21687 s` Lo que es mas que bien a diferencia de tu codigo anterior que tardaba algo de 24s

Answer (score 2):

Para mejorar los tiempos de ejecución usa `i * i` en lugar de `pow(i, 2)`.

```
def squaresum(n):
    """Returns the sum of squares of first n natural numbers.

    Parameters:
    n (int): positive integer.

    Returns:
    (int): sum of squares from 1 to n (inclusive).
    """
    return sum(i * i for i in range(1, n + 1))
```

Comment: Otra optimización que se puede hacer a este código es quitar los corchetes de  `sum([i * i for i in range(1, n + 1)])` ya que sino primero se crea una lista y luego se la recorre. En cambio sin los corchetes, se crea un objeto generador.

Comment: Gracias; siempre se me olvida el detallito.

Comment: De nada Candid Moe c:

Answer (score 2):

Puedes ir haciendo la suma a medida que haces el for:

```
import time

def squaresum(n):
    total = 0
    operands = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        aux = pow(i, 2)
        operands.append(aux)
    for op in operands:
        total = total + op
    return total


def squaresum2(n):
    val = 0
    for x in range(1, n + 1):
        val += x * x
    return val

numero = 10_000_000

i = time.time()
print(squaresum(numero))  # Devuelve 333333383333335000000
f = time.time()
print(f'Tiempo: {f-i}')  # Tiempo 3.2003238201141357

i = time.time()
print(squaresum2(numero))  # Devuelve 333333383333335000000
f = time.time()
print(f'Tiempo: {f-i}')  # Tiempo 0.7048771381378174
```

Y si lo único que quieres es modificar tu código, te bastaría con devolver la suma de `operands` que ya es una lista con los cuadrados (aunque es más rápido aprovechar el bucle `for` para la suma, como te he puesto antes):

```
def squaresum(n):
    total = 0
    operands = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        aux = i * i
        operands.append(aux)
    return sum(operands)
```